# JavaFX: How to increase text size without increasing container (Label, Button) size?

Tags: java, css, javafx

I would like to simply have the text inside a `Button` to fill more of the `Button` or increase the font size in a button without increasing its size.

I tried using negative padding but it does not give the desired result.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply remove the padding using the `-fx-padding` property:

```
.button {
    -fx-padding: 0;
    -fx-font-size: 20;
}
```

[image]